# Angular2 http.get without Rxjs

Tags: javascript, http, angular

Is it a way to simply fetch the data(in angular2) without implementing Observable and Response dependencies into the service? I found it redundant for one simple request.

Answer (score 3):

No, even if you do it in pure Javascript you have to go the callback route, just that the implementation with the `Observable` is way cleaner and easier to handle.

You **can** do synchronous requests, but since Javascript runs in one thread only, you will block the whole page until the request finishes, so it's strongly discouraged:

```
// DON'T TRY THIS AT HOME OR PRODUCTION OR ANYWHERE ELSE
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", theUrl, false); // false for synchronous request
request.send(null);
let response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular2 can use promises for Http if you prefer them over Rxjs.

```
return this.http.get("/some/url")
         .toPromise();
```

This is not sychronous though, you would need to chain a `.then(response)` method to get your result.